# How to start up with Lightning Enabled VF page or Lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, visualforce-component

I don't have any experience in Lightning so far, currently we have a Challenge to Develop a new VF page to replace a page in Console. It seems to be Lightning type of page. Please find the image below.

[image]

How can I get start with the development?

Comment: its never too late to start gaining experience, you should start with https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules

Answer (score 0):

You can use **lightning:tabset** and **lightning:tab** to create this sort of view.